# Свойство атрибута класса

Tags: python, классы

Добрый вечер. Есть класс (mongoengine):

```
class BaseMetaDocument(Document): 
    unit = StringField(..., readonly = True)
    name = StringField(..., readonly = False)
    active = BooleanField(...)
```

Не для всех атрибутов определено свойство readonly, поэтому при выводе на форму использую код:

```
    ...
    try:
        readonly = v.readonly
    except:
        readonly = False
    info = dict(..., readonly = readonly)
    return info
```

Вопрос: может можно как то записать "в одну строку"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно воспользоваться функцией [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
readonly = getattr(v, 'readonly', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть встроенная функция для проверки наличия поля/метода: `hasattr`.

```
    if hasattr(a, 'property'):
        a.property`
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python